# DisplayAlert Method causing crash in xamarin.form

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash

I'm using two entry in my xamarin form application. I want to check whenever the user click on a button, if these entries are empty display an error. currently i'm using the following method:

```
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnAirflow.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnPressure.Text))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Please fill all required information.", "OK");

        }
```

The code is working fine in debug mode on emulator. But when I changed it to release mode or create an apk file from it and testing on a physical device it cause crash.
Can you please guide me how I can fix the problem.

Comment: Are you calling DisplayAlert from UI thread, right?
Use `await DisplayAlert(...)`.

Comment: when I add await it displays this error: Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: so what's the problem? Error says clearly what you have to do.
Your method that uses `await`s has to be `async`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: I don't think there is a problem in my coding. Because the application runs well in debug mode and displayalret method works fine there. The crash only happen in release mode or  apk file.

Comment: Could you please add the code of whole method that calls DisplayAlert? Just update the initial post.

Comment: Wrap it in a try catch and enable developer instrumentation tools in Android project properties and then post the exception you receive

Comment: Try to invoke it in Main Thread `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
      DisplayAlert("Error", "Please fill all required information.", "OK");         
});`

Comment: @Janwilx72 I did that. This time because of try and catch the app didn't crash but no exception is shown in visual studio. How can I access the exception?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT unfortunately it didn't work. the app is still crashing.

Comment: @afshinbr Set a breakpoint in the catch

Comment: @afshinbr In the catch phrase, show exception in a label. Maybe something else is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Please fill all required information.", "OK");         
});
```

Comment: Im already tried that without any results. The problem is in Linking option. It cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make you button click as async method and add await just like below :

```
public async Task YourButtonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnAirflow.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnPressure.Text))
        {
            await  DisplayAlert("Error", "Please fill all required information.", "OK");
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your xaml and c# both code for button?

Answer (score 0):

Actually my problem is solved by changing linking option to None in the properties. But now my apk size is too large. Is there any option to reduce that?

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer,which will help more people  :)